Is it normal for journal reviewers to reject submissions based on non-scientific reasoning?
Is it normal for reviewers to use nonfactual statements as reasons to reject journal submissions? Here, nonfactual statements will be defined as statements that are in contradiction with verified textbooks. Has anyone else experienced this?

Backstory/details:
I have recently submitted to and appealed a physics paper at a very well known journal. For anonymity, the journal will not be named. In both cases, the initial decision and appeal were rejected by separate reviewers. Neither reviewer addressed any direct issues with the submitted work. One of the reviewers acknowledged the work for its novelty and originality.
Reviewer 1, had rejected my work based on their misinterpretation of a well renowned textbook (General Relativity - Wald, as a cross reference every other textbook agrees with Wald) and made up their own "fact" behind this misinterpretation and used it as a reason to reject. It was a completely false claim.
I applied for an appeal with a new reviewer. The initial false statements of Reviewer 1 were tossed as reasoning to reject as they were not used again. However, Reviewer 2 brought up another point which they used as justifications to reject my work. This point also did not have any direct objection to my work but addressed the foundations of my work. Again, this claim was also false and in disagreement with what textbooks say. Unfortunately, after the appeal attempt I am no longer allowed to further fight the decision. I will be going to another journal.
In both cases, the reviewers were proven to be wrong by direct textbook citations. The foundational reasons they used to reject my work, if true, would invalidate entire branches of serious research in gravitational physics as well as the textbooks themselves. My research is a specific case scenario within a well established and pre-existing branch of physics.

It seems a lot of you have concerns for the specific details. I will provide some more insight below:
All reviewer concerns did not touch the main section of the paper and were all focused on separate topics of the "Background and Introduction" and "Conventions and Refresher Section" at the very beginning.
Reviewer 1 had rejected the paper due to a choice of convention with definition X. The reviewer went on to cite the textbook General Relativity - Wald Section Y stating that the textbook said we had to use definition Z. Upon reading cited Section Y, it is apparent that there is no mention of forcing definition Z. Reviewer 1 made up their own statement. This journal publishes works frequently using definition X, so this should not be an issue to begin with.
Reviewer 2 had rejected the paper due to an "erroneous" derivation in the convention/refresher section. In this section, we provided useful definitions and derivations to derive the framework used in the paper. The "erroneous" derivation is almost word for word copy and pasted from the original literature as well as cross referenced to every textbook for consistency and correctness. Because he deemed this step "erroneous" he deemed everything else after to be incorrect. As with above, this journal as well as every other journal frequently publishes papers using the same framework given by this derivation.
In both cases, the reviewers did not present an argument against the actual works and methods in the submitted manuscript.
Upon inspection of the final email communication, both reviewers are part of the editorial board and it was not sent out for real peer review evaluation by independent reviewers.

I think everyone here can sympathize with being on the receiving end of a disappointing rejection. A Q&A site isn't the best venue for venting about it, though. If the rejection was really on such weak technical grounds as you say, though, what more can random people on the internet advise than to resubmit it somewhere else appropriate?

@user176372 I'm asking if this is a common issue that others has also experienced (non scientific opinions being used as facts in academic journals). Is so then this is a discussion to be had as a scientific community.

This isn't a discussion site, it's a Q&A site.

The discussion doesn't need to happen here. But answers confirming or denying having this specific experience would fit into Q&A.

Welcome to Academia.SE! Your question receives many downvotes in particular because of its emotional tone. You may consider rephrasing the title and question in a more neutral tone that translate more information than emotion. I think that your question raises an important issue and deserves attention.

Thank you @DmitrySavostyanov I will revise it promptly!

I agree with Dmitry here, for what it's worth. If this question were edited down, included the possibility that the author is incorrect, and removed the auxiliary discussion-based "How can this be avoided..." part, I think it's within scope. We probably have a dupe target somewhere for "Do reviewers or editors frequently reject on incorrect technical grounds?" though.

Yes, it's all-too-common for referees to be hasty or prejudicial, partly due to wanting to get the job off their desk. Yes, all-too-often leading to mistakes.

@user176372: We probably have a dupe target somewhere for "Do reviewers or editors frequently reject on incorrect technical grounds?" though. – I doubt that. While that question can be theoretically be answered within the rules of our site, it will practically only attract opinions and anecdotes. There is no way to properly study this question: You cannot collect peer reviews and have them peer-reviewed and you cannot conduct a meaningful survey, because either side believes to be correct.

If so, how can we as a scientific community avoid this issue in the future? – This site is about how academia is, not how it should be.

@Wrzlprmft and user176372 thank you for your input, I will revise the question again.

Is it normal in physics to cite textbooks? Are you also citing the original source material the textbook is drawing from? If so, why do you need to also cite the textbook? If not, are you sure the material in the textbook isn't just a simplified summary that leaves out some details for educational purposes?

@anjama Yes, it's quite common to cite a small number of textbooks in physics papers, particularly graduate level textbooks. Some such books are genuinely standard resources on a topic or technique. Other textbooks may be cited for various reasons, including "we adopt the convention/notation used in book X that's probably on your shelf". Other textbook citations can come in the intro, and play a role similar to citations to review articles.

A recommendation to accept or reject is an opinion. As such it is very normal to be based not only on facts, but on general impressions and subjective beliefs, by definition.

In my experience it is not uncommon for reviewers to state wrong claims in their reviews. My submissions received the following criticism from reviewers:

Manuscript claims X, but X is wrong, so reject (yes, X is indeed wrong, no, the manuscript never claims X).
It is known that X, but manuscript says Y, so reject (yes, X is well-known, yes, manuscript says Y, no, X does not contradict Y)
The proof of theorem T on page N is too hard to understand, so reject (there is no theorem T, and actually no proof on page N)
Obviously, from X it follows Y, hence Z, so reject (all statements are true, none are related to the submitted manuscript).

Having reflect on these experiences, I made the following notes for myself:

Academic publishing relies on unpaid work of reviewers and sometimes editors.
Unpaid work has low priority. It can be done well, but often it is not. People are too busy.
Reviewers are rarely held responsible for the quality of their reviews. Since they are not paid, it is not even clear how they can be held responsible for it.
Some reviewers are power-hungry, and some actively attempt to delay publications of their competitors and hurt their academic career.

As a community we can do the following:

Light is the best disinfection. We should evolve the publication system towards much greater transparency. For example, make all submissions publicly available, make all reviews publicly available, made authors' responses and rebuttals publicly available, make reviewers' and editor's names publicly available after the decision is made. Keep all submissions and all peer-review process publicly available, whether the submission is accepted or not.

Treat peer-review as work. Compensate reviewers financially and attach responsibility for the timeliness and academic quality of their reviews.



I don't have anything against your answer per se, I just don't think it's great to encourage rant questions with responses.

@user176372 I do not see the question as rant. It is a serious issue in academia that is rarely discussed. There is a serious power imbalance in author-reviewer relationship, that can and often does hurt early career researchers.

We'll have to disagree on whether the question was a rant as originally written then, but it has been updated. I'm locked on the downvote unless you edit, unfortunately.

@user176372 I did not intend for the post to be a rant, and apologize for any emotional wording. I am genuinely trying to see if this is a common issue.

@user176372 What edits do you suggest for my answer?

I have had a paper rejected twice because the referee didn't read past page three or so when the issue they presented had been directly answered and addressed on page four or so. Sometimes people don't referee papers in good faith. There's not much that can be done about that.

I'll answer the title of the post: "Is it normal for journal reviewers to reject submissions based on non-scientific reasoning?"
Empirically, no, it isn't. As editor-in-chief of a computational mathematics journal, I read every review that ever comes across my desk, which is ~150 per year. At least in my field, and for this journal, I would say that 90% are well informed and carefully written (though occasionally too short) and the remaining 10% are so short that they don't contain much information. I have not come across any over the past 6 years for which -- to the degree that I understood the specific topic -- the reviewer was just plain wrong or used non-scientific reasoning. I have had a single case where an author complained about a biased reviewer and in that case think that perhaps both reviewer and author insisted too much on their perspective.
In summary, having seen perhaps 1,000 reviews, I don't think what you describe is "normal".

I recognize, of course, that that's not really what you were asking. But I have nothing to say about your specific case.

There’s a catch though: Part of the asker’s problem is that the editor followed the reviewers’ decisions and thus probably considered them correct or couldn’t check due to lack of subject knowledge. Likewise you cannot know whether you just missed cases where “the reviewer was just plain wrong or used non-scientific reasoning”. Now you might say that nobody even complained about this, but then most authors are wise enough to not phrase their rebuttals like this. (And just to be clear: This is not about your actual editorial qualities; I think the question is fundamentally unanswerable.)

@Wrzlprmft Perhaps. But I also have conversations with my associate editors about the reviews they receive, and they do not report these sorts of issues either, even though they are much closer to the subject matter of the papers. I've also published ~70 papers myself, getting ~150 reviews, and have not had had this experience myself. I just don't think that it is "normal" or even "happens frequently".

I think this question is difficult to answer without knowing what the exact disagreement is. After having seen hundreds, perhaps thousands, of reviews, I've never seen a reviewer espouse crankery. However, I have seen reviewers disagree with authors over more subtle issues that can nonetheless resemble what you see.
Example: suppose there's an important parameter in your field, and two different methods to measure it are giving two different results, A and B. Your new work uses this parameter as an input, and you've chosen to use A. Your referee is strongly convinced, however, that B is correct. If your referee is right, then your entire work is wrong, and deserves to be rejected. Of course, you chose to use A because you think it's correct, and you think your reasons are well-grounded in textbooks. (Your referee surely thinks the opposite.)
Example: no referee is ever going to say "this paper claims 2+2=4, but 2+2=5, so it must be wrong. Reject". If you ever get a review of this sort, it would be highly abnormal. A reviewer could, however, say "this paper claims 2+2=4, but they also make this assertion that, if true, would lead to 2+2=5. The paper is contradictory. Reject".
Therefore, depending on how serious the disagreement is, the answer to this question varies from "it is absolutely abnormal" to "it is completely normal".

No, it is not normal. Usually reviewers are experts in the general area in which they review, and they should be familiar with textbook material. So, first of all, consider the possibility that you might be in the wrong, especially if this happens more than twice.
In any case, reviewers are your first prototypical readers. If they have major concerns about the groundwork of your paper, then the paper should be amended, even if it is 100% correct as it is: you should add explanations that make the tricky points clearer and address their issues. If you dismiss their feedback and continue, other future readers will have the same concerns about your paper. I suggest you to adopt the mindset that "reviewers are always right, even when they're wrong": address their doubts, and add more explanations. See if you can find an illuminating example, for instance. Sometimes you have to convince people that you are right.

Although I agree with all your points, it is easy to see how the mindset "I am right even when I am wrong" coupled with lack of accountability can lead to exploitative, dominating and power-hungry behaviour of reviewers towards authors

@DmitrySavostyanov Agreed; I myself find particularly obnoxious "plz cite my work" requests from reviewers. But here I was assuming that OP observed a genuine technical mistake, not a malicious false statement made in order to get the paper rejected.

@DmitrySavostyanov It could lead to this kind of behavior, but the empirical evidence presented in the answers here says that it doesn't actually lead to this kind of behavior, at least not frequently.

@WolfgangBangerth It may depend on your perspective. As an editor-in-chief, you are at the top of academic publishing hierarchy. As an early career researcher, I experienced abusive and unprofessional reviews coupled with factually incorrect statements. I can not say it was frequent (about 10%), but sufficient to have a severely demoralising and traumatic impact on my perception of academic publishing, as well as damaging my academic career. I should add that editors in my experience did not interfere with such behaviour, and anonymity protects the reviewers.

@WolfgangBangerth You also should acknowledge the survivorship bias. Here on academia.SE you collect opinions of active academics. They are people who so far survived the "publish or perish" academic game. You should not take the word (or "empirical evidence" as you say) of survivors as an unbiased estimate.

@FedericoPoloni In this case, I am only wrong if the well established techniques and conventions are wrong. I have provided more details in my most recent edit. If the two separate concerns were found to be true, the entirety of gravitational physics would be upended and these two reviewers deserve to immediately be awarded with Nobel Prizes by invalidating thousands of rigorous publications by many well renowned researches who have even received Nobel Prizes for their works!

All jokes aside, I agree that we should always consider the possibility of being wrong. But in this case, it is not even my works they are arguing with.

@DmitrySavostyanov This is a useful observation about my own publications, but as I mention in my answer, I see a lot of reviews and these are for papers of all kinds -- good ones, bad ones, for established researchers, and for junior researchers. Surely not all of these authors are going to make it in academia. Yet, I don't see the reviews in my practice that would discourage these authors.

In short your papers can and will be rejected for every possible reason you can imagine, fair and unfair, true and false, scientific and unscientific. I've had paper rejected in all these circumstances.  No journal has an obligation to publish any of your manuscript  and can decide not to for whatever reason they want.
Get used to it. Always assume when you submit a paper that it will be rejected. And be thinking of where you'll submit next as soon as you've press go on a submission.

Indeed, among the many reasons one might get a rejection, I might actually be happy with a completely off-base review - if you really believe there's nothing to fix, you can just send it elsewhere immediately without a single edit.

@NuclearHoagie I share the same sentiment as you. I view it as a good sign that they couldn't find any real and valid reason to object.

Without addressing the details of your submission, I would like to point out a few details of a functioning review process.
First, reviews are always an educated opinion of peers, hence the term 'peer review'. The value of peer reviews depend on the quality of the editors choosing the reviewers, hopefully educated peers that can evaluate the manuscript from an unbiased point of view. So a few questions here is whether the review selection has been performed according to appropriate guidelines. Note that this does not preclude the selection of reviewers that may express negative views of your work as little as selection of exclusively positively inclined reviewers. There is always a little room for randomness in the inclination of possible reviewers here. That said the role of an editor is always to convey the main points of the feedback to the author.
Second, and this follows on the first point, the role of the editor is to act as a moderator between the reviewers and the author, keeping the main role of the journal in mind. It is my (highly personal) view that editors tend to skip their responsibility in favour of reviewers comments. In an ideal world the views of reviewers and authors should be seen as views in an educated debate and not favouring one or the other side. Editors not engaging in the possibly conflicting views between author and reviewers is not doing their work. Unfortunately this seems to be be an increasing point of dissatisfaction that I deem is die to a lack of resources (time) on behalf of everyone involved in the  review process (editors, reviewers and authors).
In the case of ending up in perceived conflicts, I would strongly advice to consult the Committee on Publication Ethics COPE and browse through their cases. The Committee is intended for editors but is equally of value to authors.
